# sonata_admin.field_description.associationadmin is null

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

In Sonata Admin I have issue - when trying to create new News post (app_dev.php/admin/sonata/news/post/create), I always have sonata_admin.field_description.associationadmin null.. Am I missing something in configuration? Sonata Admin, Media and News is installed.. It crashes in form_admin_fields.html.twig line 59 . Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want a solution, you might add some information like PHP classes, configuration etc...

Comment: The project is started from the scratch, I don't know what files would be helpful for this.. config.yml and composer would be enough?

Comment: Well, explain then what do you mean from scratch. How did you install it? The sandbox? Which version? etc etc... Please not that just having a paragraph telling you have an error without any context will not help us at all.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nWteNNVa config.yml
http://pastebin.com/RKWTef2E composer.json , let me know if you would need more...

Comment: Donc link pastebin like that. You are on StackOverflow. Just edit your question to have a proper presentation accompagned by pasted code.